# How do I create a Pandas Dataframe from a dictionary containing a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am working on a project where I am getting JSON data from a GraphQL API. After receiving the data, I am using json.loads() on the data and then accessing parts of the JSON I need, which is then stored in a dictionary containing another dictionary. The dictionary is:

```
{'placement': 1, 'entrant': {'id': 8554498, 'name': 'Test'}}
{'placement': 2, 'entrant': {'id': 8559863, 'name': 'Test'}}
{'placement': 3, 'entrant': {'id': 8561463, 'name': 'Test'}}
{'placement': 4, 'entrant': {'id': 8559889, 'name': 'Test'}}
{'placement': 5, 'entrant': {'id': 8561608, 'name': 'Test'}}
{'placement': 5, 'entrant': {'id': 8560090, 'name': 'Test'}}
{'placement': 7, 'entrant': {'id': 8561639, 'name': 'Test'}}
{'placement': 7, 'entrant': {'id': 8561822, 'name': 'Test'}}
{'placement': 9, 'entrant': {'id': 8559993, 'name': 'Test'}}
{'placement': 9, 'entrant': {'id': 8561572, 'name': 'Test'}}
```

How could I create a Pandas Dataframe so that the columns are

```
placement |  id  |  name
```

and the values below those columns are the values associated with them from the dictionary? If I use just

```
pd.DataFrame()
```

the output is not as desired, so I tried to look up solutions that involved me iterating over the items in the dictionary but I was unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is the shared data wrapped in a list? kindly provide the complete sample form, with expected output

Comment: I was going to ask the same- if there are brackets or commas somewhere along the rows, and what is the type and len of df_data1

Comment: It is not wrapped in a list. It is just exactly as shown in my post. The type of df_data1, per type(), is a <class 'dict'>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it by extracting a new DataFrame from inside the first one and merging it:

```
from itertools import chain

import pandas as pd

data = [
    [{"placement": 1, "entrant": {"id": 8554498, "name": "Test"}}],
    [{"placement": 2, "entrant": {"id": 8559863, "name": "Test"}}],
    [{"placement": 3, "entrant": {"id": 8561463, "name": "Test"}}],
    [{"placement": 4, "entrant": {"id": 8559889, "name": "Test"}}],
    [{"placement": 5, "entrant": {"id": 8561608, "name": "Test"}}],
    [{"placement": 5, "entrant": {"id": 8560090, "name": "Test"}}],
    [{"placement": 7, "entrant": {"id": 8561639, "name": "Test"}}],
    [{"placement": 7, "entrant": {"id": 8561822, "name": "Test"}}],
    [{"placement": 9, "entrant": {"id": 8559993, "name": "Test"}}],
    [{"placement": 9, "entrant": {"id": 8561572, "name": "Test"}}],
]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(chain(*data))
result_df = pd.merge_asof(
    df.loc[:, df.columns != "entrant"],  # Get df without the "entrant" column
    df["entrant"].apply(pd.Series), left_index=True, right_index=True
)
```

Here is the result:

```
   placement       id  name
0          1  8554498  Test
1          2  8559863  Test
2          3  8561463  Test
3          4  8559889  Test
4          5  8561608  Test
5          5  8560090  Test
6          7  8561639  Test
7          7  8561822  Test
8          9  8559993  Test
9          9  8561572  Test
```

Comment: This works when I tested it with your data, but it does not work when tested with my data because my df_data1 variable is not stored within one list as a whole. When I attempt to store it in a list, it stores it like this: https://pastebin.com/Bbe9jDjs. It treats the df_data1 dictionary is just one entry in the list.

Comment: @binarycoffee356 I see, I edited my answer to support nested lists using itertools (a built-in module).

Comment: I am getting a key error on 'entrant'. I suspect it is because your data is an array with comma-separated dictionaries, while mine is just a list containing one entry.

Comment: Actually, this worked perfectly, even without the edit. It was just a slight issue on my end. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create proper dictionaries for pandas to create a dataframe. I'm assuming here you have a list of dicts called dictionaries.

```py
pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"placement": d["placement"], "id": d["entrant"]["id"], "name": d["entrant"]["name"]}
        for d in dictionaries
    ]
)
```

Comment: Well, I do not have a list of dicts. The way in which I created and stored the dictionary is by doing the following in a loop:  df_data1 = json_data['data']['event']['standings']['nodes'][j], where json_data is the variable holding the JSON data and df_data1 becomes the dictionary in my post. Using your solution, I am getting an error that the string indices must be integers.

Comment: So, are all rows a unique dictionary containing dictionaries, or is every row a separate dictionary as well?

Comment: Well, it has been a while since I have written Python, so my answer may not be entirely correct, but from the dictionary I posted in my post, it looks to me like it is one dictionary containing a unique dictionary on every row. The dicitionary I posted is exactly what I see when I print its contents. If I print the items of the dictionary, I can see they are 'placement' and 'entrant' if that helps to better understand its structure.

Answer (score 1):

i would do something like this, maybe is not the most elegant solution, but it works. I asume that you have a list of every dict, cause you proportioned the dicts one by one

```
dList = [{'placement': 1, 'entrant': {'id': 8554498, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 2, 'entrant': {'id': 8559863, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 3, 'entrant': {'id': 8561463, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 4, 'entrant': {'id': 8559889, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 5, 'entrant': {'id': 8561608, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 5, 'entrant': {'id': 8560090, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 7, 'entrant': {'id': 8561639, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 7, 'entrant': {'id': 8561822, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 9, 'entrant': {'id': 8559993, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 9, 'entrant': {'id': 8561572, 'name': 'Test'}}]


#generate column Names I supose that you dont have writed this names to make more general the problem
d0 = dList[0]
columns = []
for key,val in d0.items():
    if not isinstance(val,dict):
        columns.append(key)
    else:
        for subkey,subval in val.items():
            columns.append(subkey)

#%% Here we are going to generate de data list (a list with a sublist for every dict
data = []
for d in dList:
    thisData = []
    for key,val in d.items():
        if not isinstance(val,dict):
            thisData.append(val)
        else:
            for subkey,subval in val.items():
                thisData.append(subval)
    data.append(thisData)


df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)
```

hope it works for you, if not let me know

Comment: What if my dictionary is not being stored in a list? It is stored in a variable, df_data1, and is assigned by doing the following in a loop: df_data1 = json_data1['data']['event']['standings']['nodes'][j].

Comment: sorry I cannot understand well, you have multiple dictionarys called df_data1, df_data2 and so?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion. The reason I am looping is because the "nodes" portion of the JSON is an array of n length. I am looping to access all of the data for every node but I am just storing it in one variable, df_data1, which then becomes the dictionary in my original post.

Comment: So if you have a dictionary containig dictionaries (that also contain one dict more), let's call them
orig_dict (the dict that contain dicts)
placeDict (the {'placement': 1, 'entrant': {'id': 8554498, 'name': 'Test'}} )
and subdict (the entrant) 
then replace
for d in dList: 
by
for d in orig_dict.values(): 

this migth work leme know

Comment: This is an ok solution, but optimization wise it would be quite bad due to the python loops. As a general rule of thumb for pandas and other data-science oriented tools: The less pure-python processing you have to do the better.

Comment: This produces KeyError because dList != df_data1, dList here is wrapped in a list

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iterate over the df_data1 capturing all dictionaries because of the way json.loads() provides the data. In order to fix the structure of the dictionary as wanted, I suggest you do the following to add commas between the dictionaries by replacing any occurrences of `"}{`" with `"}, {"`, and surround it with `"["` and `"]"`. Suppose `j` your json string, then:

```
df_data1 = json.loads("[" + j.replace("}{", "}, {") + "]")
```

Now your df_data1 should look like this:

```
[{'placement': 1, 'entrant': {'id': 8554498, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 2, 'entrant': {'id': 8559863, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 3, 'entrant': {'id': 8561463, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 4, 'entrant': {'id': 8559889, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 5, 'entrant': {'id': 8561608, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 5, 'entrant': {'id': 8560090, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 7, 'entrant': {'id': 8561639, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 7, 'entrant': {'id': 8561822, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 9, 'entrant': {'id': 8559993, 'name': 'Test'}},
{'placement': 9, 'entrant': {'id': 8561572, 'name': 'Test'}}]
```

And now you can use @Thomas Q solution:

```
df= pd.DataFrame([
        {"placement": d["placement"], "id": d["entrant"]["id"], "name": d["entrant"]["name"]}
        for d in df_data1
        ])
df
    placement   id  name
0   1   8554498 Test
1   2   8559863 Test
2   3   8561463 Test
3   4   8559889 Test
4   5   8561608 Test
5   5   8560090 Test
6   7   8561639 Test
7   7   8561822 Test
8   9   8559993 Test
9   9   8561572 Test
```